# How to prevent multiple event calling with jQuery on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is that sometimes on select change `$('selector').on('change', ...)` function is fired multiple times.

Generally when I'm using `.on` function then I always add `.off()` function and it works great. But in this case I can't use the off function due to the fact that off function is disabling the select input (I mean that it does not change).

I've tried to add `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` but it is not the solution.

JS:

```
$('#addMealToMenuDiet').on('change', function(event) {
  //then ajax function is called
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="addMealToMenuDiet" class="form-control">
    ...
</select>
```

How can I avoid such a situation?

---

**Solution**

Unfortunately my on change method was placed in another on click method. Therefore it was called multiple times...

Comment: Are you creating the `addMealToMenuDiet` element dynamically?

Comment: for each time you run the js above, it will count up firing the event

Comment: No the #addMealToMenuDiet is not created dynamically. What is your point?

Comment: With only the code you have given, there is not such behaviour. Provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most possibly your code runs multiple times, you could simply always unbind the event before you bind it just put your ajax stuff into a function in before your other code

```
function myAjaxfunction(){
 //...
}
```

and then run this to initialize your select

```
$(document).off("change", '#addMealToMenuDiet', myAjaxFunction).on("change", '#addMealToMenuDiet', myAjaxFunction)
```

this way you are on the save side ;)